# How to write test case for @viewchild element referenced for input type checkbox in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jasmine

I am new to angular test case. I have a input type checkbox which has element ref id of #checkbox.
Below is code snippet. How to write test case for masterToggle function in below code? If anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('checkbox') checkbox;

function masterToggle(){
this.checkbox.nativeElement.checked = false;
this.checkbox.nativeElement.indeterminate = false;
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="nodecheckbox" #checkbox [disabled]="isCheckboxDisabledForSelectAll()" (change)="masterToggle(data)" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of testing is to verify, if a functionality is behaving accordingly to the dev expectation. Starting from here we should test if masterToggle method sets checked property to false and indeterminate to false.

Inside a test file in Angular you have access to all public methods, and eventually by using bracket notation(Mycomponent[privateMethodOrPropertyName]). So this actually allows you for easy testing.

```
it('should be ok', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      let checkbox = fixture.debugElement.query(/*you should locate yourcheckbox*/);

      component.masterToggle();
      // if model doesn't update use fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(checkbox.nativeElement.checked).toBe(False);
      expect(checkbox.nativeElement.indeterminate).toBe(False);
    });
```

Comment: let checkbox = fixture.debugElement.query(/*you should locate yourcheckbox*/);
'you should locate yourcheckbox' what should define here ?
based upon my html code.

Comment: you can read more on fixture debugging element at https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#debugelement.
It allows you to use query selectors or css, or other ways to locate your element, such as a class or id. Should be easy once you check the documentation

Comment: okay thanks will check that